# Some site logos are not visible on action bar in SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, favicon

Certain site logos, like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) :

[image: U&L logo]

and [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) :

[image: UX.SE logo]

have a dark blue shade. This matches the shade of the color of the action bar in the app leading to partially visible icons:

[image: Ampersand.SE]

This needs to be fixed so that icons are visible in their entirety.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.83<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been "fixed": the app *removed* the site logo on the action bar.

[image: action bar]

On related topic, perhaps the next issue is on "Your Sites" with dark blueish-gray background, but I don't think it's offending as much as the one on action bar (still visible).

[image: your sites]